# Socket.io chat in dashboard

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, chat

I am new with Socket.io and I have a question about it. I am making a kind of helping website where the visitors can ask a question and some moderators can answer them.

I followed this "tutorial" http://socket.io/get-started/chat/ . When I go to localhost:3000, I see the chat and it works. But the chat needs to be on some kind of dashboard and the question was how can I do that?

Example:

http://localhost/admin/dashboard

```
////// CHAT //////   ///// Settings ///// ///// Statistics ////
```

How can I "include" the chat so it will be on this page?

Hope this is understandable and someone can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: You just need to create a html file, where you can embed your chat panel, and serve that file on a specific URL. Assuming you use node.js server, you could employ Express framework to serve your pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [implement Nodejs app in already existing website](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30644373/implement-nodejs-app-in-already-existing-website)